# Magento newsletter auto checked on registration Page

Tags: magento, newsletter, subscribe

I'm running magento 1.7.0.2 and I want the checkbox of the newsletter subscription on the registration page checked by default. I have followed a few hacks but they were all written for older versions of magento.
Here's a link to one of the hacks which I tried and didn't work: [Force newsletter subscription in Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3447922/force-newsletter-subscription-in-magento)

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
<div class="account-create">
<div class="page-title">
    <h1><?php echo $this->__('Complete your profile') ?></h1>
</div>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('form_fields_before')?>
<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>
<?php /* Extensions placeholder */ ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('customer.form.register.extra')?>
<form action="<?php echo $this->getPostActionUrl() ?>" method="post" id="form-validate">
    <div class="fieldset">
        <input type="hidden" name="success_url" value="<?php echo $this->getSuccessUrl() ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="error_url" value="<?php echo $this->getErrorUrl() ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="success_url" value="<?php echo $this->getSuccessUrl() ?>" />
        <h2 class="legend"><?php echo $this->__('Personal Information') ?></h2>
        <ul class="form-list">
            <li class="fields">
                <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('customer/widget_name')->setObject($this->getFormData())->setForceUseCustomerAttributes(true)->toHtml() ?>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="email_address" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input type="text" name="email" id="email_address" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getFormData()->getEmail()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?>" class="input-text validate-email required-entry" />
                </div>
            </li>
            <?php if ($this->isNewsletterEnabled()): ?>
            <li class="control">
                <div class="input-box">
                     <li>
     <input type="checkbox" name="is_subscribed" title="<?php echo $this->__('Sign Up for Newsletter') ?>" value="1" id="is_subscribed" <?php if($this->getFormData()->getIsSubscribed()){ ?> checked="checked"<?php }elseif($this->getFormData()->getIsSubscribed == NULL){ ?> checked="checked"<?php }?> />
    <label for="is_subscribed"><?php echo $this->__('Sign Up for Newsletter') ?></label>
</li>
                </div>
                <label for="is_subscribed"><?php echo $this->__('Sign Up for Newsletter') ?></label>
                <?php /* Extensions placeholder */ ?>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('customer.form.register.newsletter')?>
            </li>
            <?php endif ?>
        <?php $_dob = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('customer/widget_dob') ?>
        <?php if ($_dob->isEnabled()): ?>
            <li><?php echo $_dob->setDate($this->getFormData()->getDob())->toHtml() ?></li>
        <?php endif ?>
        <?php $_taxvat = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('customer/widget_taxvat') ?>
        <?php if ($_taxvat->isEnabled()): ?>
            <li><?php echo $_taxvat->setTaxvat($this->getFormData()->getTaxvat())->toHtml() ?></li>
        <?php endif ?>
        <?php $_gender = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('customer/widget_gender') ?>
        <?php if ($_gender->isEnabled()): ?>
            <li><?php echo $_gender->setGender($this->getFormData()->getGender())->toHtml() ?></li>
        <?php endif ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
<?php if($this->getShowAddressFields()): ?>
    <div class="fieldset">
        <input type="hidden" name="create_address" value="1" />
        <h2 class="legend"><?php echo $this->__('Address Information') ?></h2>
        <ul class="form-list">
            <li class="fields">
                <div class="field">
                    <label for="company"><?php echo $this->__('Company') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" name="company" id="company" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getFormData()->getCompany()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Company') ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('company') ?>" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <label for="telephone" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Telephone') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" name="telephone" id="telephone" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getFormData()->getTelephone()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Telephone') ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('telephone') ?>" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        <?php $_streetValidationClass = $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('street'); ?>
            <li class="wide">
                <label for="street_1" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Street Address') ?></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input type="text" name="street[]" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getFormData()->getStreet(1)) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Street Address') ?>" id="street_1" class="input-text <?php echo $_streetValidationClass ?>" />
                </div>
            </li>
        <?php $_streetValidationClass = trim(str_replace('required-entry', '', $_streetValidationClass)); ?>
        <?php for ($_i = 2, $_n = $this->helper('customer/address')->getStreetLines(); $_i <= $_n; $_i++): ?>
            <li class="wide">
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input type="text" name="street[]" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getFormData()->getStreet($_i)) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Street Address %s', $_i) ?>" id="street_<?php echo $_i ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $_streetValidationClass ?>" />
                </div>
            </li>
        <?php endfor; ?>
            <li class="fields">
                <div class="field">
                    <label for="city" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('City') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" name="city" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getFormData()->getCity()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('City') ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('city') ?>" id="city" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <label for="region_id" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('State/Province') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <select id="region_id" name="region_id" title="<?php echo $this->__('State/Province') ?>" class="validate-select" style="display:none;">
                            <option value=""><?php echo $this->__('Please select region, state or province') ?></option>
                        </select>
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                        //<![CDATA[
                            $('region_id').setAttribute('defaultValue', "<?php echo $this->getFormData()->getRegionId() ?>");
                        //]]>
                        </script>
                        <input type="text" id="region" name="region" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getRegion()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('State/Province') ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('region') ?>" style="display:none;" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="fields">
                <div class="field">
                    <label for="zip" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Zip/Postal Code') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" name="postcode" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getFormData()->getPostcode()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Zip/Postal Code') ?>" id="zip" class="input-text validate-zip-international <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('postcode') ?>" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <label for="country" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Country') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <?php echo $this->getCountryHtmlSelect() ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <input type="hidden" name="default_billing" value="1" />
        <input type="hidden" name="default_shipping" value="1" />
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
    <div class="fieldset">
        <h2 class="legend"><?php echo $this->__('Login Information') ?></h2>
        <ul class="form-list">
            <li class="fields">
                <div class="field">
                    <label for="password" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Password') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" title="<?php echo $this->__('Password') ?>" class="input-text required-entry validate-password" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <label for="confirmation" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Confirm Password') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="password" name="confirmation" title="<?php echo $this->__('Confirm Password') ?>" id="confirmation" class="input-text required-entry validate-cpassword" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('form.additional.info'); ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons-set">
        <p class="required"><?php echo $this->__('* Required Fields') ?></p>
        <p class="back-link"><a href="<?php echo $this->escapeUrl($this->getBackUrl()) ?>" class="back-link"><small>&laquo; </small><?php echo $this->__('Back') ?></a></p>
        <button type="submit" title="<?php echo $this->__('Submit') ?>" class="button"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Submit') ?></span></span></button>
    </div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var dataForm = new VarienForm('form-validate', true);
    <?php if($this->getShowAddressFields()): ?>
    new RegionUpdater('country', 'region', 'region_id', <?php echo $this->helper('directory')->getRegionJson() ?>, undefined, 'zip');
    <?php endif; ?>
//]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is what worked for me. If you want the newsletter opt in on the customer account registration page checked by default, get this file:
/app/design/frontend/your_theme/default/template/customer/form/regist‌​er.phtml

Find this line:

```
<?php if ($this->isNewsletterEnabled()): ?>
```

Right below it, add this:

```
<?php
$checked = true;
if($this->getFormData()->getEmail()) {
if(!$this->getFormData()->getIsSubscribed()) {
    $checked = true;
    }
}   
 ?>
```

Then Find this div

```
<div class="input-box">
```

Replace the code in the div with this code:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="is_subscribed" title="<?php echo $this->__('Sign Up for Newsletter') ?>" value="1" id="is_subscribed" checked="checked" class="checkbox" />
```

That's it! Save and upload the file.

Comment: This worked for me in 1.6.2.0.  FYI, the other solution by Pankaj has "$checked = false" within the if block, but the one that worked has $checked = true... might be something to consider if you're trying the other solution..  This one works well though, I tested with new users both cases (subscribed and unsubscribed), and the control panel reflects the subscription properly.

Comment: Be sure to ALSO edit the /app/design/frontend/your_theme/default/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml as well if you are using the Persistent Cart module.

Comment: how did you use $checked variable?

Answer (score 1):

Please find the following code in register.phtml file:

```
<?php if ($this->isNewsletterEnabled()): ?>
        <li class="control">
            <div class="input-box">
                 <li>
             <input type="checkbox" name="is_subscribed" title="<?php echo $this->__('Sign Up for Newsletter') ?>" value="1" id="is_subscribed" <?php if($this->getFormData()->getIsSubscribed()){ ?> checked="checked"<?php }elseif($this->getFormData()->getIsSubscribed == NULL){ ?> checked="checked"<?php }?> />
            <label for="is_subscribed"><?php echo $this->__('Sign Up for Newsletter') ?></label>
        </li>
    </div>
    <label for="is_subscribed"><?php echo $this->__('Sign Up for Newsletter') ?></label>
    <?php /* Extensions placeholder */ ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('customer.form.register.newsletter')?>
</li>
<?php endif ?>
```

And **Replace** with the following code :

```
<?php if ($this->isNewsletterEnabled()): ?>
<?php
$checked = true;
if($this->getFormData()->getEmail()) {
    if(!$this->getFormData()->getIsSubscribed()) {
        $checked = false;
    }
}   
 ?>
<li class="control">
<div class="input-box">
    <input type="checkbox" name="is_subscribed" title="<?php echo $this->__('Sign Up for Newsletter') ?>" value="1" id="is_subscribed"<?php if($checked): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> class="checkbox" />
</div>
<label for="is_subscribed"><?php echo $this->__('Sign Up for Newsletter') ?></label>
<?php /* Extensions placeholder */ ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('customer.form.register.newsletter')?>
</li>
<?php endif ?>
```

I have used php for this because. by this we can get user preference after user submit 
form and error occur

Hope this Help !!

Comment: Hi Pankaj, thanks so much for your help. I'm a little confused however. Here is how the register.phtml code appears in my files. I have pasted the code in my question. What do I replace? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Vim I have updated my answer, Please try with this one .. Hope this Help !!

Comment: thanks for your effort Pankaj. It still didn't work for me. The box still remains unchecked.

Answer (score -1):

Please Add the following code in register.phtml file:

Add chaked End of line Input type

```
<input type="checkbox" name="is_subscribed" title="<?php echo $this->__('Sign Up for Newsletter') ?>" value="1" id="is_subscribed"<?php if($this->getFormData()->getIsSubscribed()): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> class="checkbox" checked />
```