# Newsletter checked as default in Magento 1.7

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework

I want to have the newsletter checked by default in checkout page. I am using Onepagecheckout. I have already searched here, but no solution yet, maybe because I am using Onepagecheckout.

I can make the checkbox be ticked by default by adding `checked="checked"` in the input, but this doesn't subscribe the customer.

Here is my code from `onepagecheckout.phtml`:

```
<?php if (Mage::helper('onepagecheckout')->isSubscribeNewAllowed()) : ?>
    <p class="newsletter">
        <input type="checkbox" id="newsletter-signup" name="newsletter" value="1" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('newsletter')->__('Sign up for our newsletter') ?>" class="checkbox" checked="checked" />
        <label for="newsletter-signup">
            <?php echo Mage::helper('newsletter')->__('Sign up for our newsletter') ?>
        </label>
    </p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Any suggestions to my problem?

Comment: Maybe this will help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12906602/magento-newsletter-auto-checked-on-registration-page

Comment: Hi. I have allready tried that but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I found out myself. I replaced input with:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="is_subscribed" title="<?php echo $this->__('Sign Up for Newsletter') ?>" value="1" id="is_subscribed" checked="checked"/>
```